# ui:include value is evaluated before preRenderView

Tags: jsf-2

page1.xhtml

```
<h:body>
<h:link outcome="page2.xhtml>
<f:param name="id" value="1"/>
</hlink>
</h:body>
```

page2.xhtml

```
 <h:body>
    <f:metadata>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{myBean.init}"/>
    </f:metadata>
    <ui:include src="#{myBean.myString}"/>
    </h:body>
```

MyBean.java

```
public void init(ComponentsystemEvent e){
  Map<String,String> params = 
  FacesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
  String myId = params.get("id");
  int id = Integer.parseInteger(myId);
  if(id==1)
    setMyString = "myPage.xhtml";
}
```

While i am navigating from page1.xhtml to page2.xhtml i am sending an id as a parameter where according to this id i will display a page

the problem is that the page cannot be find

i am printing in console what's happening what i found is that it is evaluating getMyString() before going to preRenderView init so why is this happening like this

i also tried post construct it returned error in resource injection of managedBean

Comment: PostConstruct seems more correct. Post the stacktrace

Answer (score 4):

That's a classic view build time vs view render time problem: `<ui:include>` is a tag handler that's evaluated at **view build time**, while `<f:event type="preRenderView">` naturally is called just when the **view is about to be rendered**. As you guess, the latter event happens *after* the former, while you *expect* it to be otherwise. Still, when the former tag requests to evaluate its attribute, it's definitely `null`, or isn't there yet.

Read the classic **[JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3343681/1820286)** to get a better grasp at what's the relationship between these two phases of JSF lifecycle.