# JSF <ui:include> contains page with preRenderView event not trigger in <h:body>

Tags: html, jsf, events, jsf-2, prerenderview

I am using JSF 2.0.1 and observe a difference when try to add `header.xhtml` onto other page with `<ui:include src="header.xhtml"></ui:include>`, the code example below:

**header.xhtml**

This page will be add as one component onto major page, it contains `preRenderView` event used for checking whether user is permitted to log on that major page.

```
<h:head>
    <title>Header</title>
</h:head>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{authorize.checkAuthentication}"/>
<h:body></h:body>
```

If I am using `<ui:include src="header.xhtml"></ui:include>` **inside** `<h:body>` section on major page as below:

**Major.xhtml**

```
<h:head>
    <title>Major</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <ui:include src="header.xhtml"></ui:include>
    <f:view></f:view>
</h:body>
```

The problem is `<f:event>` in `header.xhtml` not triggered, in another word `checkAuthentication` function **not work** in this case.

But if I move `<ui:include src="header.xhtml"></ui:include>` out of `<h:body>` section on major page and **put it ahead of** `<h:body>`, the event triggered and function works.

```
<h:head>
    <title>Major</title>
</h:head>
<ui:include src="header.xhtml"></ui:include>
<h:body>       
    <f:view></f:view>
</h:body>
```

Could someone help me to explain why this difference happens ? Is there any professional way to solve this case, as keep the header page content and also trigger the event ? Thanks

Note: Also I check on [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16544674/uiinclude-value-is-evaluated-before-prerenderview), but not sure we are the same case